# Lookup Field Intermittent Results

Tags: visualforce, lookup, bug

We have a lookup field that will sometimes return results and sometimes will not return results, and since it is a required field, users have to exit out of the form and return.

I am wondering if anyone else has experienced similar behavior? And if anyone has any ideas!

There is a filter on the lookup field, but it is optional and when the problem occurs, if the filter is removed, results still do not return.

If a user has results under 'Recent Items' in the lookup window, they can select one but the Id does not get linked and so they still have to exit out of the form and return.

Users have also reported that bandwidth may be a factor, the problem is more frequent when using mobile data out of the office rather than a good wifi connection.

```
<apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
  <apex:outputLabel value="Ship From" for="shipFrom" />
  <apex:actionRegion>
    <apex:inputField value="{!newLine.Ship_From__c}" id="shipFrom" required="true">
      <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" rerender="shipTo" action="{!calltoControllerToValidate}" />
    </apex:inputField>
  </apex:actionRegion>
</apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
```